# YouTube API: console.log(player.getCurrentTime()); works in the console, but not when loaded from js file

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Folks, could use help with the YouTube API's getCurrentTime() command.

My problem?  It works in the console, but not in the browser when loaded via a .js file.

Re-performing this problem:

Run this command after calling a new iframe youtube "player": 
   console.log(player.getCurrentTime());

When run in the console, the correct answer: 0 (because it was run on page load).

When run in the .js file: Nothing in the console.  Should read "0".

Note: The console.log command is listed at the end of the .js file, and the .js file is loaded right before the closing body tag.

Thoughts?

Comment: `Thoughts` - I think you need to change the javascript as per what I'm thinking

Comment: Give us the full code to your working project and we'll see what we can do.